# What are the possible output characters of sha512?

Tags: php, hash, sha512

What are the possible characters for `$code`:

```
$randStr = "some random string that contains only: [a-zA-Z0-9_]";
$code = hash('sha512', $randStr);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SHA512 will generate **128** characters of lowercase HEX characters (0 to f), e.g.

> a9046c73e00331af68917d3804f70655a9046c73e00331af68917d3804f70655a9046c73e00331af68917d3804f70655

See [the documentation for `hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) for more information.

Comment: so can I match the output with /^[0-9abcdef]+$/ ?

Comment: @Mohsin, Yes you can.

Comment: +1 anyway, since yours is way more clear and succinct than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

SHA_512 will generate 130 characters

0xFFF50A71FE36FA45829B4E7F2426D25758635235335C39C11089B27805312BD73C83ACD3B71EAF47267368AEEDA289A4A2F7A191BABA1A3CAB9A2543CC06BC65